# How to listen an input on nodejs not take the value with bodyparser

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to "listen" an input text field at nodejs ?

I want to use a search input on my html page and i want to listen "live" any value that user types. Not to take the final value with a submit button and body parser.

I try to add an event listener after select my html input, but my selector is undefined.

**here is my server.js file**

```
    // 3rd part modules
    const express = require('express')
    const hbs     = require('hbs')
    const fs      = require('fs')
    const moment  = require('moment')

    // App modules
    const userData = require('./fetch')

    // App basic configs
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
    const app = express()

    //Log when someone is on app
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        const now = moment().format("D MMM YYYY, HH:mm")
        const clientIp = req.ip
        const log = `${now}: from ${clientIp}`
        fs.appendFile('server.log', `${log}\n`, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err
        })
        next()
    })

    // Maintenance mode
    // app.use((req, res, next) => {
    //     res.render('maintenance.hbs', {
    //         pageTitle: 'Maintenace mode'
    //     })
    // })

    // Express middleware to store public files & static pages
    app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`))

    // View engine Handlebars
    app.set('view engine', 'hbs')

    // Use partials for header and footer
    hbs.registerPartials(`${__dirname}/views/partials`)

    // Pass custom functions everywhere
    hbs.registerHelper('getCurrentYear', () => {
        return new Date().getFullYear()
    });

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('home-page.hbs', {
            welcomeMessage: 'Welcome to home page',
            pageTitle: 'Home page',
            location: userData.location,
            currentTemp: userData.currentTemp,
            feelTemp: userData.feelTemp
        })
    })

    // Don't forget the command to nodemon to see changes on hbs files
    // nodemon server.js -e js,hbs,html,css

    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server is up on ${port}`)
    })
```

**Here is my fetch.js file**

```
// 3rd part library
const axios = require('axios')

// Input selection
const locationInput = document.querySelector('#locationInput').value()

// Encode user data & Use it to fetch his location
const encodedAddress = `greece${encodeURIComponent(locationInput)}`
const geocodeUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${encodedAddress}&key=AIzaSyAnzbpJRrrx9xl2ZjRdwOx4APrn-zgVscM`

const getWeatherData = async (encodedAddress) => {
    const location = await axios(geocodeUrl)

    if (location.data.status === 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
        throw new Error('Unable to find that address.')
    }
    const lat = location.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat
    const long = location.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
    const weatherUrl = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/95886b065ed14ca53b317610064fe04a/${lat},${long}?units=ca`

    const weatherData = await axios.get(weatherUrl)
    return {
        location,
        weatherData
    }
}

getWeatherData(encodedAddress).then((info) => {
    const location = info.location.data.results[0].formatted_address
    const currentTemp = info.weatherData.data.currently.temperature
    const feelTemp = info.weatherData.data.currently.apparentTemperature

    return {
        location,
        currentTemp,
        feelTemp
    }

}).catch((e) => {
    if (e.code === 'ENOTFOUND') {
        console.log('Unable to connect to API servers')
    } else {
        console.log(e.message)
    }
})

module.exports = {
    location,
    currentTemp,
    feelTemp
}
```

**And here is my html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

    {{> header}}

    <p>{{welcomeMessage}}</p>
    <p>This is home page</p>
    <input id="locationInput" type="text" placeholder="Location">
    <p>{{location}}</p>
    <p>{{currentTemp}}°C</p>
    <p>Feels like {{feelTemp}}°C</p>
    {{> footer}}

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Nodejs is the backend, you can't listen to any changes in the DOM or in the JS on the client. You would have to setup an api route in nodejs which you post the value to when input field's value is changed.

Comment: Is this possible  ? To set up a post route and receive live the changing  value of the input field  ?

Comment: "I try to add an event listener after select my html input, but my selector is undefined."
Are you sure your listener is correct ?

Comment: @VindhyachalKumar i upload it

Answer (score 1):

You can use event `onchange` of that input to send request like `ajax` or [socket.io](https://socket.io/),etc.

`onchange` may be is different (`onChange` in [reactjs](https://reactjs.org/), `.change()` method for [jquery](https://jquery.com/), ...)

Comment: This event listener must live on a different script on HTML ? I want to get the value of this search  input INSTANTLY and directly fetch data from an API at server side

Comment: What is "live" ?
In your server, you can listen request from user (with html and javascript).
 You think they can request to you from ...

Comment: I mean that i dont want to use a submit button on this input field.
I want to get directly the value when a user changes it...

But i get that document is not defined when iam starting the app

Comment: My way don't need use submit button, just check input change with event onchange.

Comment: You can request server side(nodejs) method when there is a change in input at frontend. All you need to do is to request a method of node js during change event of HTML input field.

Comment: @Ｈｏｎｇａｒｃ How can i select an HTML element, if my console says that document is undefined ? "document.queryselector()" is not working inside of my server.js file... So i can't select the element and attach an event listener to it.

Comment: @NirajPaudel Can you help me to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you tell me what is code to select your input, I will try.

Comment: "const locationInput = document.querySelector('#locationInput').value();"
You should push to you script of client, not server.

Comment: Up above is my html file, i want to select with document.querySelector('#locationInput') the input element 
inside from server.js file and manipulate the value here.

Comment: @Ｈｏｎｇａｒｃ Ok i can run your selector inside of a script that lives on html file...how this value is accessible on server.js file ?

Comment: You can request to your server, you should listen it with app.get or app.port or use socket.io same my answer

Comment: change port -> post